# Windows containers on Windows 10 Anniversary Update are not working

Tags: windows, containers

I just upgraded to the Windows 10 [Anniversary Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1607_(Anniversary_Update)) (1607, 2016-08-02) and wanted to try Windows containers.

I followed the most recent guide I could find: *[Windows Containers on Windows 10 by Neil Peterson](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10)* (subject to change!!)

But when coming to the Docker run, it could not start the container:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker run -it nanoserver cmd
docker: Error response from daemon: container a39ea9f033493807343489ac180b4469f910db22f93f9364271a6d1aeb077e7b encountered an error during CreateContainer failed in Win32: A connection could not be established with the Virtual Machine hosting the Container. (0xc0370108) extra info:
{
  "SystemType": "Container",
  "Name": "a39ea9f033493807343489ac180b4469f910db22f93f9364271a6d1aeb077e7b",
  "Owner": "docker",
  "IsDummy": false,
  "VolumePath": "",
  "IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot": true,
  "LayerFolderPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a39ea9f033493807343489ac180b4469f910db22f93f9364271a6d1aeb077e7b",
  "Layers": [
    {
      "ID": "db459b08-938e-562d-8408-eec0e6df9871",
      "Path": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\261aeaeac3268a5dbb10dd77a9a91344d9192377fdf69e9f208561927d56a185"
    }
  ],
  "HostName": "a39ea9f03349",
  "MappedDirectories": [],
  "SandboxPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter",
  "HvPartition": true,
  "EndpointList": [
    "7cde146d-dc65-44da-8a6e-6d72c58ec44c"
  ],
  "HvRuntime": {
    "ImagePath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\261aeaeac3268a5dbb10dd77a9a91344d9192377fdf69e9f208561927d56a185\\UtilityVM"
  },
  "Servicing": false
}
.
```

I did not get to try this on the insiders builds. What should I expect to happen when running? - should it start a Hyper-V machine (this does not happen when checking in Hyper-V manager at least).

#### Update

With the updated deamon and client from the link in the answer I got a new errors:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker run -it nanoserver cmd
docker: Error response from daemon: container 48465da53f47156755cc6a7c7bd48a0f5a76db9fb9c6c77d52a481ffb9412d10 encountered an error during Start failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3): Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

#### Update 2

With the updated docker(d).exe and running daemon in debug a little more information is made available:

```
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.797745800+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.25/containers/create"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.798769400+02:00" level=debug msg="form data: {\"AttachStderr\":true,\"AttachStdin\":true,\"AttachStdout\":true,\"Cmd\":[\"cmd\"],\"Domainname\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"Env\":[],\"HostConfig\":{\"AutoRemove\":false,\"Binds\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceReadIOps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteBps\":null,\"BlkioDeviceWriteIOps\":null,\"BlkioWeight\":0,\"BlkioWeightDevice\":null,\"CapAdd\":null,\"CapDrop\":null,\"Cgroup\":\"\",\"CgroupParent\":\"\",\"ConsoleSize\":[50,120],\"ContainerIDFile\":\"\",\"CpuCount\":0,\"CpuPercent\":0,\"CpuPeriod\":0,\"CpuQuota\":0,\"CpuShares\":0,\"CpusetCpus\":\"\",\"CpusetMems\":\"\",\"Devices\":[],\"DiskQuota\":0,\"Dns\":[],\"DnsOptions\":[],\"DnsSearch\":[],\"ExtraHosts\":null,\"GroupAdd\":null,\"IOMaximumBandwidth\":0,\"IOMaximumIOps\":0,\"IpcMode\":\"\",\"Isolation\":\"\",\"KernelMemory\":0,\"Links\":null,\"LogConfig\":{\"Config\":{},\"Type\":\"\"},\"Memory\":0,\"MemoryReservation\":0,\"MemorySwap\":0,\"MemorySwappiness\":-1,\"NetworkMode\":\"default\",\"OomKillDisable\":false,\"OomScoreAdj\":0,\"PidMode\":\"\",\"PidsLimit\":0,\"PortBindings\":{},\"Privileged\":false,\"PublishAllPorts\":false,\"ReadonlyRootfs\":false,\"RestartPolicy\":{\"MaximumRetryCount\":0,\"Name\":\"no\"},\"SecurityOpt\":null,\"ShmSize\":0,\"UTSMode\":\"\",\"Ulimits\":null,\"UsernsMode\":\"\",\"VolumeDriver\":\"\",\"VolumesFrom\":null},\"Hostname\":\"\",\"Image\":\"nanoserver\",\"Labels\":{},\"NetworkingConfig\":{\"EndpointsConfig\":{}},\"OnBuild\":null,\"OpenStdin\":true,\"StdinOnce\":true,\"Tty\":true,\"User\":\"\",\"Volumes\":{},\"WorkingDir\":\"\"}"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.803744400+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath Flavour 1 ID eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.803744400+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (1)"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.805747000+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (2)"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.805747000+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath succeeded flavour=1 id=eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028 path=C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.806784800+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::CreateLayer Flavour 1 ID 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init parent eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.807742100+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::CreateLayer  - succeeded id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init parent=eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028 flavour=1"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.808789000+02:00" level=debug msg="WindowsGraphDriver Get() id 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init mountLabel "
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.808789000+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::ActivateLayer Flavour 1 ID 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.810743400+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::ActivateLayer  - succeeded id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init flavour=1"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.820779900+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::PrepareLayer flavour 1 layerId 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.820779900+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::NameToGuid Name eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.822782500+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::PrepareLayer succeeded flavour=1 layerId=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.822782500+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath Flavour 1 ID 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.823748800+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (1)"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.824805600+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (2)"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.824805600+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath succeeded flavour=1 id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init path=C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.825745400+02:00" level=debug msg="WindowsGraphDriver Put() id 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.825745400+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::UnprepareLayer flavour 1 layerId 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.826743000+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::UnprepareLayer succeeded flavour 1 layerId=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.826743000+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::DeactivateLayer Flavour 1 ID 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.827742100+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::DeactivateLayer succeeded flavour=1 id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.827742100+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath Flavour 1 ID 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.827742100+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (1)"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.828742000+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (2)"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.828742000+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath succeeded flavour=1 id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init path=C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d-init"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.829741100+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::CreateSandboxLayer layerId 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d parentId C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.839745200+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::NameToGuid Name eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.850753600+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::CreateSandboxLayer - succeeded layerId=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d parentId=C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.919412900+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.25/containers/991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d/attach?stderr=1&stdin=1&stdout=1&stream=1"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.919412900+02:00" level=debug msg="attach: stdin: begin"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.920414800+02:00" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: begin"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.920414800+02:00" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: begin"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.925413100+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.25/containers/991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d/start"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.935412900+02:00" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint determined_cori's interface on network nat"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.939416500+02:00" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(172.16.0.0/12, <nil>, map[])"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.955490000+02:00" level=debug msg="Network Response : { \"ComputedPolicies\" : [ { \"ACL\" : [ { \"Type\" : \"ACL\" } ] } ], \"CreateProcessingStartTime\" : 131148175799534514, \"DNSServerList\" : \"192.168.1.1\", \"GatewayAddress\" : \"172.16.0.1\", \"ID\" : \"d9d1a429-a5e1-42ab-80f4-750ac39e0085\", \"IPAddress\" : \"172.21.185.228\", \"MacAddress\" : \"00-15-5D-AA-98-9B\", \"Name\" : \"New HNS Endpoint\", \"Policies\" : [ { \"Type\" : \"ACL\" } ], \"PrefixLength\" : 12, \"Type\" : \"nat\", \"Version\" : 4294967297, \"VirtualNetwork\" : \"09f8ccf4-f4b9-49c5-8af3-451f4d3b6241\", \"VirtualNetworkName\" : \"nat\" }"
time="2016-08-04T22:52:59.956487100+02:00" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint determined_cori's interface on network nat"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.041390200+02:00" level=debug msg="WindowsGraphDriver Get() id eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028 mountLabel "
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.041390200+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::ActivateLayer Flavour 1 ID eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.044393800+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::ActivateLayer  - succeeded id=eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028 flavour=1"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.045358600+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::PrepareLayer flavour 1 layerId eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.046369900+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::PrepareLayer succeeded flavour=1 layerId=eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.046369900+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath Flavour 1 ID eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.047370600+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (1)"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.048361400+02:00" level=debug msg="Calling proc (2)"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.048361400+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::GetLayerMountPath succeeded flavour=1 id=eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028 path=C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.048361400+02:00" level=debug msg="WindowsGraphDriver Put() id eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.049362900+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::UnprepareLayer flavour 1 layerId eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.049362900+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::UnprepareLayer succeeded flavour 1 layerId=eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.050363600+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::DeactivateLayer Flavour 1 ID eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.050363600+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::DeactivateLayer succeeded flavour=1 id=eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.051361500+02:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: client.Create() with spec {{0.3.0 (Windows) {windows amd64 10.0.14300} {true [50 120] {} [cmd] [] C:\\} { false} 991cfcfd8913 []} {0xc082367f40 0xc082367f20 true C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d [C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028] 0xc08246a270}}"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.051361500+02:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::NameToGuid Name eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:00.051361500+02:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::CreateContainer id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d config={\"SystemType\":\"Container\",\"Name\":\"991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d\",\"Owner\":\"docker\",\"IsDummy\":false,\"VolumePath\":\"\",\"IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot\":true,\"LayerFolderPath\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d\",\"Layers\":[{\"ID\":\"555536ae-3dc2-5751-90ce-0a62b0e6f1eb\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028\"}],\"HostName\":\"991cfcfd8913\",\"MappedDirectories\":[],\"SandboxPath\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\docker\\\\windowsfilter\",\"HvPartition\":true,\"EndpointList\":[\"d9d1a429-a5e1-42ab-80f4-750ac39e0085\"],\"HvRuntime\":{\"ImagePath\":\"C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\docker\\\\windowsfilter\\\\eb86ef45aec4a9564e29aadc351548926ce5cba2a057e2eb618fff531fd3f028\\\\UtilityVM\",\"SkipTemplate\":true},\"Servicing\":false}"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:02.859064500+02:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::CreateContainer succeeded id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d handle=45552032"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:02.859064500+02:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: Create() id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d, Calling start()"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:02.864062800+02:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: starting container  991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:02.864566900+02:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::Container::Start id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.402144600+02:00" level=debug msg="Result: {\"Error\":-2147024893,\"ErrorEvents\":[{\"Data\":[{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Value\":\"991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d\"},{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Value\":\"%%2147942403\"},{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Value\":\"0x80070003\"},{\"Type\":\"Guid\",\"Value\":\"D9D1A429-A5E1-42AB-80F4-750AC39E0085\"}],\"EventId\":12105,\"Message\":\"Failed to create network adapter for Container '991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d', network endpoint ID '{D9D1A429-A5E1-42AB-80F4-750AC39E0085}': The system cannot find the path specified. (0x80070003).\",\"Provider\":\"17103e3f-3c6e-4677-bb17-3b267eb5be57\"}],\"ErrorMessage\":\"The system cannot find the path specified.\"}"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.403140900+02:00" level=error msg="container 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d encountered an error during Start failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.409141900+02:00" level=error msg="libcontainerd: failed to start container: container 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d encountered an error during Start failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.409141900+02:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::Container::Terminate id=991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.410151700+02:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: cleaned up after failed Start by calling Terminate"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.410151700+02:00" level=error msg="Create container failed with error: container 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d encountered an error during Start failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.411149600+02:00" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: end"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.412147600+02:00" level=debug msg="attach: stdin: end"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.413142700+02:00" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: end"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.481751900+02:00" level=debug msg="Releasing addresses for endpoint determined_cori's interface on network nat"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.481751900+02:00" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(172.16.0.0/12, 172.21.185.228)"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.501524300+02:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.25/containers/991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d/start returned error: container 991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d encountered an error during Start failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3): Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type"
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.503496900+02:00" level=debug msg="Closing buffered stdin pipe"
```

So as one of the commons indicate, there could be a problem with network interfaces in hyperv.

```
time="2016-08-04T22:53:03.402144600+02:00" level=debug msg="Result: {\"Error\":-2147024893,\"ErrorEvents\":[{\"Data\":[{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Value\":\"991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d\"},{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Value\":\"%%2147942403\"},{\"Type\":\"String\",\"Value\":\"0x80070003\"},{\"Type\":\"Guid\",\"Value\":\"D9D1A429-A5E1-42AB-80F4-750AC39E0085\"}],\"EventId\":12105,\"Message\":\"Failed to create network adapter for Container '991cfcfd8913196b488479944dd44104b707fc325cebef7382c21d82eacf305d', network endpoint ID '{D9D1A429-A5E1-42AB-80F4-750AC39E0085}': The system cannot find the path specified. (0x80070003).\",\"Provider\":\"17103e3f-3c6e-4677-bb17-3b267eb5be57\"}],\"ErrorMessage\":\"The system cannot find the path specified.\"}"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some trial and error I finally got into my nanoserver container.

Please read over all the comments and answers in this Stack Overflow question to get the full scope.

First make sure you are using the latest Docker image from https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/live/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10.md as outlined in one of the answers here.

If you followed the original documentation you can simply update your `docker` and `dockerd` with the following two commands (remember to do `stop-service docker` and  `dockerd --unregister-serice` first).

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://master.dockerproject.org/windows/x86_64/dockerd.exe -OutFile $env:ProgramFiles\docker\dockerd.exe
Invoke-WebRequest https://master.dockerproject.org/windows/x86_64/docker.exe -OutFile $env:ProgramFiles\docker\docker.exe
```

You should now have

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker --version
Docker version 1.13.0-dev, build 979d48b
```

or later.

Don't start the Docker deamon or register it as a service just yet.

To clean up anything I had that might create issues I ran `DEVMGMT.MSC` from start and removed any Hyper-V network adapters (remember if you use Hyper-V for other VMs, don't remove those).

I started the deamon : `dockerd -D` and then I created a new adapter:

```
docker network create -d nat MyNatNetwork
```

I then stopped the deamon and started it again with `dockerd -D --bridge "none"` and then I was able to start my nanoserver:

```
docker run -it nanoserver cmd
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/728840f8-e38a-4b8b-ab1e-6ce7abd83687/dockerd-fails-to-start-error-initializing-network-controller-on-windows-10-build-143521002?forum=windowscontainers

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a49c5cf8-b089-4421-bb12-ffa84f63a65c/docker-network-ls-is-showing-2-nat-networks?forum=windowscontainers

Comment: Also, for those updating from **docker 1.12** versions to **1.13**, you should first delete all the contents from`%ProgramData%\docker` (you will need to take ownership first) otherwise you will get `The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)` errors , and instead of manually downloading nanoserver images, use `docker pull microsoft/nanoserver`.

Comment: While this solves my problem, too (I get _failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)_), it does not seem to allow the containers to connect to the network. Also, `docker network create -d nat MyNatNetwork` fails for me with _The parameter is incorrect_.

Comment: I'm on `version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87` and was having `container a62...73 encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)` while running `docker build` and this fixed it for me though I'm still getting suspicious network errors in the daemon output.

Comment: I've gotten past my previous error but have added some svn calls to dockerfile and they are failing with either 'no such host' or 'connection timed out' depending on whether dockerd is bridged to 'none' or any other network. I've verified the host is resolvable and accessible.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Was in exactly the same situation. However, after upgrading the Docker images, my error changed to a timeout (different from yours).

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container 219aa480b05d7c7f8110b734dee75e3c2e1a66e230ca066f5e463f0976092476 encountered an error during CreateProcess failed in Win32: The remote procedure call failed. (0x6be) extra info: {"ApplicationName":"","CommandLine":"cmd","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":false,"ConsoleSize":[40,100]}.
```

I then applied the registry hack that the instructions said was required for a known issue with the technical preview.  I'd assumed it was no longer required with the official release, but apparently it is, because I can now connect to the container. Try:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization\Containers' -Name VSmbDisableOplocks -Type DWord -Value 1 -Force
```

Comment: Could you share your NetNat, VMSwitch and NetAdapter configs so that we can compare ours to yours. I believe my problem is located in one iof those.

Comment: I'm guessing these are Hyper-V configuration files?  If so, I'm sorry but I don't know where to find them.  This my first use of Hyper-V; I'm a long-time VMware user.  However, I haven't touched anything other than following the above instructions.  If it helps, when the container is running, nothing show up in the Hyper-V Manager.  Otherwise, let me know where to find said files.

Comment: The 3 things above are configurations that can be queried via PowerShell like so: `Get-NetNat | Format-List *`, `Get-VMSwitch | Format-List *`, `Get-NetAdapter | Format-List *`. Feel free to remove the MAC Adresses from the output. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: "after upgrading the docker images" do you mean docker.exe and dockerd.exe ? or actual nanoserver images? where you found those

Answer (score 0):

The [updated documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/live/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10.md) on GitHub for Windows builds 14372+ has instructions to download a newer version of the Docker daemon and client which work properly on the Anniversary Update.

Comment: I added an error that i got from using the updated deamon and client :(

Answer (score 0):

megamorf, I am not sure if it was my settings you were after? You probably wanted Poul's as it was him messing around with the network configuration. I didn't touch the settings, but if it helps here's my output from running `Get-NetNat | Format-List *, Get-VMSwitch | Format-List *, Get-NetAdapter | Format-List *`

```
Store                            : Local
TcpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpInboundRefresh                : False
Active                           : True
Caption                          :
Description                      :
ElementName                      :
InstanceID                       : H77edae10-e10d-41e1-ada2-8592df522752;0
ExternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix :
IcmpQueryTimeout                 : 30
InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix : 172.16.0.1/12
InternalRoutingDomainId          : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Name                             : H77edae10-e10d-41e1-ada2-8592df522752
TcpEstablishedConnectionTimeout  : 1800
TcpTransientConnectionTimeout    : 120
UdpIdleSessionTimeout            : 120
PSComputerName                   :
CimClass                         : root/StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetNat
CimInstanceProperties: {Caption, Description, ElementName, InstanceID...}
CimSystemProperties: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```