# Windows Container on Windows 10 Insider Build and Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, containers

I'm on the latest insider preview build for Window 10 (14955.rs_prerelease.161020-1700).  I'm also using the most current Docker for Windows (1.12.3-beta29.2 (8280)).  I have a Docker build for a simple nanoserver image.  When I run the image I get the following error.

> docker: Error response from daemon: container e0fa9da740f6ce0534516ededcce3d6f8f4c07ee656ce12e7b76b73077c52f38 encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3): Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.

Outside of using the 1.13 version of the Docker engine as outline [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10).  Is there a way to get this to work?

I would rather stick with Docker for Windows since I go back and forth (Linux and Windows) and the tooling makes it easy

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38732280 (see Update and Update 2 sections)

Comment: Could you please paste the commands you are using and your Dockerfile. I have the same docker for Windows version but I am using official windows version. I can test in my pc.

Comment: there were known container errors with previous Insider Builds. I experienced a lot of trouble when using the DfW beta versions. Docker runs fine with plain docker install as you mentioned in the link from MSDN.

Comment: Thanks @FalcoAlexander.  That is confirms what I'm seeing as well.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez I'm not building a Docker file to begin with.  Just trying to run a sample or the base image as is.